# Homomorphic encryption over finite fields

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, finite-field

I'm curious on the following question: let $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ be a finite field which is an extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ with order of $n$, is there an encoding scheme $e:=\mathbb{F}_{2^n}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ for some domain $\mathcal{C}$ and satisfies linear homomorphic, i.e. $$\forall x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}, e(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)=c_1e(x_1)+c_2e(x_2),$$where $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ are some constants.

A naive idea is that we regard $s\in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as a binary vector and encrypt the bits one by one, then we can do the arithmetic operation on $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ in the bit level over the cipher vector (which only require additive homomorphic over $\mathbb{F}_2$). However, this will have a huge cipher space i.e. $c*n$ where $c$ is the security parameter makes the bit level encryption secure.

My question is:

> Can we do better than the naive approach above? Or, is there any existed results on this topic?

Comment: Is an encoding scheme the same thing of an encrypting scheme?

Comment: @Vitor Yes, it's an encryption scheme.

Comment: I may be missing something, but, since a field is commutative, $e(cx) = e(xc)$, and so, for the equality you put there, it would be equal to $xe(c)$ and that is exposing the plaintext.

Comment: @Vitor I edited the question to make it more clear, what I need is actually the additive and constant multiplicative homomorphic encryption over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$.

Comment: This does not work. Your cipher function is always a multiplication by a constant. To see this, set $x_2=0$ and $x_1=1$. Now the equation will be $e(c_1) = e(c_1 1) = c_1 e(1)$ for arbitrary $c_1$.

Comment: @Cryptostasis Yes, you are right. The scheme won't be secure if $e$ is deterministic since the encryption of $0$ can only be 'zero' in $\mathcal{C}$, but for probabilistic scheme we can require to apply a re-encryption if we get a zero cipher in my naive approach (also it may not has a trivial inverse of $e(1)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ that you can use to extract $c_1$). Maybe I should not write is as an equation :).

Comment: @Paul there is no problem in writing it as a question.  (:    And about your edition, since $c_1$ and $c_2$ belongs to the same field that $x_1$ and $x_2$ belongs to, then everything we commented here is still valid. It doesn't matter if they are constants, because, for the encrypting function, $x_1$, $x_2$ or anything else that is received is viewed as a constant.